# jq - merge only single key from second JSON file into main JSON file

Tags: json, jq

Given:

master.json:

```
{"a":[{"x":1}], "b":1}
```

extra.json:

```
{"a":[{"x":2}], "somekey2":2, "somekey3":3}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "x": 1
    },
    {
      "x": 2
    }
  ],
  "b": 1
}
```

I need to merge into `master.json` contents of `"a"` key from `extra.json`, ignoring all other keys the second JSON may have.

Tried this, but it didn't work

```
jq -s "add" '.[a] + .[a]' x1 x2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to slurp them. Without any flags you can access the second input by `input` keyword.

```
$ jq '.a += input.a' master.json extra.json 
{
  "a": [
    {
      "x": 1
    },
    {
      "x": 2
    }
  ],
  "b": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the files are not huge in size, slurping them and appending the contents of the array `a` would suffice

```
jq -s '.[].a = ([.[].a]|add|unique)|.[0]' master.json extra.json
```

You can remove the `unique` part, if you are allowed to keep duplicate objects for the array.